# Which BugTracker have image upload/attached using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, bug-tracking

I've tryed mylyn but i cant find that feature, if anyone have test mantis or bugzilla, please tell me if one of those have that option. Thanks!

have to attach code source and show task and assign it to developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mylyn does have that option, AFAIK...
It even has a feature for taking a screenshot.

Comment: The mylyn user guide lists it as an option. 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_User_Guide

AFAIK only the desktop version that deals with office-work is not free.